# Setting CDN rules using Azure resource manager

Tags: azure, azure-cdn, azure-cli2

Want to set caching rules for Azure CDN through azure Resource manager or CLI commands. 
Tried searching, but did not get anything from the documentation. Does Microsoft provide support for setting the rules through ARM / CLI commands?

Comment: these are all the supported operations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cdn/

Comment: In this, There is No support for managing rules. Everytime, I can't create rules for portal. Is there any way, by which I can avoid manual tasks.

Comment: cant help you much, capture rest call with fiddler (from the portal) and replicate that